# Sub-Collections or Sub-Categories in Jekyll

Tags: jekyll

Is there a method built into Jekyll for forming categories and sub-categories, or collections and sub-collections?

For example:

```
├───linux
│   ├───desktops
│   └───shell
└───windows
    ├───desktop
    └───server
```

I'm currently using collections for "linux" and "windows", and can place an `index.html` page within each to create a browsable structure, however I would like to categorize posts further and programmatically display 'sub-categories', or 'sub-collections', on the website.

Answer (score 2):

I've been struggling with this need as well... no luck .

However, I think I found a workaround that may help to keep the folder structure tidy. A combination of **collections**, **naming convention**, and **permalink**.

For example:

```yml
linux-main:
    output: true
    permalink: /linux/:title/

linux-desktop:
    output: true
    permalink: /linux/desktop/:title/

linux-shell:
    output: true
    permalink: /linux/shell/:title/

windows-main:
    output: true
    permalink: /windows/:title/

windows-desktop:
    output: true
    permalink: /windows/desktop/:title/

windows-shell:
    output: true
    permalink: /windows/shell/:title/
```

In the project structure this will look like this:

```
 Project
 ┣  linux-main
 ┃ ┣ post1.md
 ┃ ┗ post2.md
 ┣  linux-desktop
 ┃ ┣ post1.md
 ┃ ┗ post2.md
 ┣  linux-shell
 ┃ ┗ post1.md
 ┣  windows-main
 ┣  windows-desktop
 ┗  windows-shell
```

And the _site folder will be:

```
 Project
 ┣  linux
 ┃ ┣ post1.html
 ┃ ┣ post2.html
 ┣ ┣  desktop
 ┃ ┃ ┣ post1.html
 ┃ ┃ ┗ post2.html
 ┣ ┗  shell
 ┃   ┗ post1.html
 ┗  windows
   ┣  desktop
   ┗  shell
```